# Pull-down to add element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, web-applications

How do you add an element when the user pulls down and list element is added using jQuery?

The interaction is similar to the clear app or the pull to refresh on twitter. I know iScroll supports this type of interaction, but I need to avoid using additional plugins.

Does anyone know of a good way to implement this using jQuery?

The list I am using can be found here: http://shaloon.com/list/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a quick and dirty example that might get you started

http://jsfiddle.net/EC657/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       var random = Math.round(Math.random()*10);
       $(".list").eq(random).clone().appendTo(".parentcontainer");
   }
});
```